# Broken link: how much should you pay your developers

Tags: bug, broken-link

Minor bug report for the blog - in [this post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/how-much-should-you-pay-developers/) the link at the bottom, to what looks like a Wordpress upload, is broken. This is the path: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/Stack-Exchange-Developer-Compensation.pdf

The original file can be found [here](http://ice.vaave.net/assets/content_files/151336557_Stack_Exchange_Developer_Compensation.pdf), and there's an existing issue on Github [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/issues/114). Thanks to commentators for pointing to those.

Comment: https://github.com/StackExchange/stack-blog/issues/114

Comment: Yeah, that's the top google hit.  Google first, ask next.

Comment: Yeah, there's a link to it on the comments of the post. I posted here because the 404 page say "If you've just run into a broken link, please report it at our feedback site."... that not actually the done thing?

Comment: (And the 'feedback site' is specifically a link to this meta page.)

Comment: Don't worry, reporting the broken link was completely reasonable.

Comment: http://ice.vaave.net/assets/content_files/151336557_Stack_Exchange_Developer_Compensation.pdf seems like the same one

Comment: Why does this "Stack Overflow" company think it's okay to outsource their feedback/support to Stack Overflow?!