# A better way to report broken links

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**Update:** This question is asking "is there a better way to report trivial break/fix issues". After reading around about Meta, I'm more convinced this system saves the developers time and works well in the Meta community.

- If I look at the bug queue, most have between -10 and 10 votes. This weighting of bug reports means the official maintainers probably *do* get added value from passing their break/fix queue through here first, because Meta commentators are a tenacious kind who investigate and downvote/upvote appropriately.
- @rene in the comments here suggested updating my question to provide a more complete picture. If even a small percentages of reporters think to do that, the community will save a considerable amount of time for the official maintainers.

It's not a system I would have guessed would work - I hope the company appreciates how dedicated the regulars here are.

---

I found a [404 error](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/Stack-Exchange-Developer-Compensation.pdf) reading an old blog post, which says "If you've just run into a broken link, please report it at our feedback site.", linking here. I thought it was weird to link to a public venue instead of a bug tracker, but I shrugged and [did as asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312221/broken-link-how-much-should-you-pay-your-developers)

Within five minutes, there were two posts saying "why didn't you google this before asking?". I already had, folks - I'd already found the document I was after, and only posted about the broken link because SO explicitly asked me to. It's a bug report, not a support request.

Anyway - I'm new here, but it seems to me like this Meta site is an interesting place, but the wrong channel for "here's a broken link, fix that some day". It's offputting for occasional guests like me to do exactly what the site asks, and get told off for not googling things - but it makes **total sense** for the community to discourage this kind of content.

Why? Because my "question" was a completely non-interactive break/fix issue, and it's using up valuable screen space while having no value or interest to 99.9% of the community. The only people who can fix old blog posts are whichever members of staff have moderator rights over there! There's a reason that bug trackers are tagged and filtered off to only the relevant people - it's because a lot of the work requested there is only actionable by a few people, and no-one else needs or wants to see it.

So: there an existing backchannel to report break/fix issues? Or, more specifically, to report things that are only relevant to SO staff, not by the community as a whole? If so, maybe the 404 page point should point there instead.

Comment: There *is* the **[contact us](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)** link at the bottom of every Stack Exchange page. This link allows you to directly contact the Stack Exchange development team.

Comment: @TinyGiant - I kinda hope it goes through a help desk before reaching any the devs directly! But, sure, it does ask you to use it if "an issue that can't be addressed by meta", and I'd say "404s in a non-user-editable section of the site" fits that requirement.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't blame you for posting that question and think you did the right thing.

So there is not much wrong with the procedure and as such I see no reason to change it.

If your google search would have found a bug report on either [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=blog+broken+link) or [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=blog+broken+link) your bug report would be a waste of your, ours and the dev teams time.

As it seems you already found the github issue I would have explicitly mentioned that in your post (show your research!) as that would take out the reason for both Hans and Pekka to jump in to comment. If you see comments as ways to improve your post you should have edited by adding the link to the github issue and a link to the missing pdf to make life of that poor dev that is going to fix this easier.

When I saw your post and the github issue I checked if I could find how that content could or should be added to the blog so I could create a pull request for the fix. As that didn't seem obvious to me I refrained from doing so.

Posts tagged with [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) are seen by SE Developers almost immediately and go into the internal bug tracking system. Due to the high number of testers (that's all of us) there is somewhat of a backlog. Expect [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) before this gets fixed. Despite the advice given in the comments I would only use the [**contact us**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) form if you have found a bug that might be exploitable and due to that nature doesn't go well with sharing with a wider audience. For the rest keep posting those on any meta as long as they are not already posted but include your research.

Last but not least: [Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) is somewhat [different](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259917/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work), voting is a little bit more harsh and its regulars/veterans leave direct comments without much fluff. Don't feel bad about it, just shrug it off and accept your slightly thicker skin now.

Comment: Thanks - as a first-time visitor to Meta, it got my back up a bit to be told off for doing what the site asked, but since then I've looked around a bit and been really impressed by the quality of discussion going on & how much thought goes into steering the community, and by the willingness of people to jump in and put work in to the site. Post edited, answer accepted :)