# New button/icon required to indicate broken links

Tags: feature-request

I read through this [A better way to report broken links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/312225/a-better-way-to-report-broken-links). I would like to know a flag can be made available just to flag an answer/question with broken links.

This way the OP knows ahead that the answer has broken links when going through an answer.  I do understand that answers have to be posted with content rather than just links as a preventive measure - but broken links happen anyway

## Edited version

If I'm reading an answer posted by someone which has broken links, I would like to a see a button or an icon which I could click to say that the link in the given answer is broken.

I do not want to raise a flag for moderator attention / approval to validate to see if a link is broken. The `Link-broken` is the feature I'd like to have.

Probably, I worded it incorrectly in the first place.

Comment: If it's a link only answer flag as VLQ, if not leave a comment to let the OP know. I don't see why we should need such feature.

Comment: Everybody can propose an edit.  So don't pass the buck to somebody else, *fix it*!

Comment: @Hans Was my 1st thought as well. The OP might simply not know how to fix that link.

Comment: @HansPassant, I do not intend to *pass the buck*, I want to leave a caution sign saying that the link is broken. With `111` reputation, I cannot edit answers, all i can do is leave a comment. So whats the point?

Comment: Of course you can edit answers. Anyone with 1 reputation can suggest an edit.

Comment: "*Suggesting an edit*" still requires someone to look into the answer and approve. And all that person can do is approve my edit. I would rather push a button and move on, rather than *pester* someone to see what I have done is right or not

Answer (score 3):

Flagging a broken link is worthless.

The way flags work is they bring a problematic post to the attention of moderators and/or community members with moderation privileges. The idea is that such users, using their moderation tools, will either fix the problem or delete the problematic post altogether. This doesn't make sense when the problem is a broken link.

There are really only two possible reactions to a broken link:

1. Edit the question to fix the broken link.

   Since editing can be done by *anyone* (either someone with full edit privileges can make the edit outright, or any user can suggest an edit for community approval), if you see a broken link, you can just edit in the fix yourself. There is no need to raise a flag, no need to introduce a level of indirection, no need to waste other people's time by getting them involved. There's nothing they can do that you cannot do yourself.
2. Delete the post outright.

   This is the draconian solution, and usually not appropriate. Just because a link has gone dead does not mean that a good answer has lost all value.

   In fact, if a link is the only thing that gives value to a post, then there is something fundamentally wrong with that post. It should have been flagged and removed a long time ago, regardless of whether or not the link had broken. As you know, link-only answers are not good answers.

   If outright deletion is really appropriate, then you can and should flag the post. But don't flag it as "has a broken link"—flag it as "not an answer" or "very low quality". That's how you flag answers that should be deleted.

I occasionally see people leave comments on my old answers informing me that one of the links has broken. I find this type of comment to be a worthless nag. I'm sorry that the link has gone dead, but I don't understand what you expect me to do about it. I do not personally host archives of all content I link to on my own server, so there's nothing magical that I can do to fix the link when it goes dead. I can either search Google for a mirror, hope to find a copy in the Wayback Machine, or delete the link outright. All of those things could have been done by the person who left the comment. Don't pester someone else to fix a problem when you can fix it yourself.

Comment: I have posted the edited version of the question below my original question.